# In IDEA, how do you enable autoimport for javadoc links?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

When writing Javadoc for a class and when I wish to add a link to another class, I type:

```
{@link SomeCl<TAB>}
```

and IDEA completes with the *full import*, ie it will yield `{@link com.foo.SomeClass}`; only afterwards can I choose to "replace with import".

Is there a way to tell IDEA to use imports in this situation instead?

(this is all the more frustrating that it does so automatically for code... Just not Javadoc)

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved. I should explore the configuration options further!

File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java, select tab "imports", there is an option to `Use fully qualified classnames in Javadoc` which was checked. Simply uncheck it...

Comment: This has changed in newer IntelliJ versions (at least >= 15). In the Java tab, you will come across a dropdown for "Use fully qualified names in JavaDoc". Select the "Never, use short name and add import" option. This matches the default in Eclipse and thus causes the fewest code diffs in the project shared amongst a mixture of Eclipse and IntelliJ developers.